# stemming library in java

Tags: java, api, stemming

Is there any library for stemming in java!?

Comment: Are we talking about: [Linguistic morphology stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an implementation of Porter's stemmer available on his [website](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt). The code is not very Java-ish, but it does what it's supposed to, plus it's only a single class.

Comment: @mad_programmer: at the end of the class file, there's a `main` method that demonstrates the use of the class.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org). It is generally written to do other things, but it does some stemming as part of its indexing process.

Comment: More specifically, Lucene's analyzers.

Comment: I want something for console application.

Answer (score 2):

Updated Answer: Porter recommends a later version of what is available on his website. That is Snowball: http://snowball.tartarus.org/  It is essentially a code generator that can generate a **Java** or C stemmer based on a stemmer specification.