# Finding synonyms and the basic form of tilted words

Tags: java, nlp, synonym

I am looking for a tool in Java that would allow me to do the following things:

1) Find for a tilted word its basic form. Example:

- For the words "connection", "connecting", "connects" and etc, it will return the word "connect".
- For the words "running", "runs" it will return the word "run".

2) Return for each words a collection of it's synonyms.

Does anybody know of such a tool?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you care only about English.

The first problem you have is called [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).  This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444943/stemming-library-in-java) recommends this Java implementation of the [Porter stemmer](http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt).

WordNet has a pretty big human created/curated database of words and their relations that includes synonyms among other things.  Here is a [Java API to WordNet](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/jwi/).

Comment: This Porter stemmer is very nice for regular verbs, but for V3 verbs it fails. Is there a tool that can complete it for successful V3 analysis?

Comment: It also fails for other verbs, like pause for example.